# Redirect not working in apache

Tags: apache, redirect

I configured the following redirection:

```
<VirtualHost ...>
  <Directory ...>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(myapp/login) https://%{HTTP_HOST}:443/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

But it's not redirecting. How can I troubleshoot it ?

Comment: Troubleshoot by enabling a RewriteLog. However, I'd just add a leading `/` to `^/(myapp/login)`

Comment: That was it! If you answer it, I'll give you the bounty

Comment: OK, elaborated a but about the how & why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General debugging: if you have access to the apache configuration itself, you can enable a [`RewriteLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) which, depending on which level you set, can give you a step-by-step breakdown of matches, current values, and alterations.

What is going on here is that there's a difference in the url matching in en entire `host` context (only available in apache's configration files), or per-directory of `.htaccess` context:

> What is matched?
>   In **VirtualHost** context, The Pattern will initially be matched against *the part of the URL after the hostname* and port, and before the query string (e.g. "/app1/index.html").
>   In **Directory and htaccess context**, the Pattern will initially be matched *against the filesystem path, after removing the prefix* that lead the server to the current RewriteRule (e.g. "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending on where the directives are defined).

The difference between the two being that in a `VirtualHost` context you have a leading `/`, in `.htcaccess` context (wich most examples on the net assume because it's more readily available) you don't have that leading `/`.

In short, here this works, but wouldn't work in `.htaccess`:

```
^/(myapp/login)
```

And if you want to make it match in both contexts, make the leading `/` optional:

```
^/?(myapp/login)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the following code worked (I think this has to do with a combination of the != (as @jason said) and the port.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(myapp/login) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be some problem in negating the lexicographic equality operator.  I wasn't able to find anything prohibiting this in the mod_rewrite documentation or elsewhere, but I also did not see examples using `!=`.  In fact, the documentation indicates that it should work, but you might try just matching "off" instead of "not on", like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

If this is the case, it would be very difficult to troubleshoot using the usual methods (e.g., using `RewriteLog`).